# PDO ON DUPLICATE KEY ERROR

Tags: pdo

I was trying really hard for the last hour to find the mistake I made in my query but couldn't find it out:

```
public function setContacts($source, $category, $contacts){
    $sql = $this->db->con->prepare("INSERT INTO nl_contacts (cSource, cCompany, cLastname, cFirstname, cMail) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?) 
                                    ON DUPLICATED KEY UPDATE  
                                    cSource    =   VALUES(cSource),
                                    cCompany   =   VALUES(cCompany),
                                    cLastname  =   VALUES(cLastname),
                                    cFirstname =   VALUES(cFirstname)");
    foreach($contacts as $contact){
        $vars = array($source,$contact['cCompany'],$contact['cLastname'], $contact['cFirstname'],$contact['cMail']);
        if($sql->execute($vars) == true){
            $this->cID = $sql->lastInsertId();
        }
    }
```

The error I get:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DUPLICATED KEY UPDATE cSource = ' at line 2'

What I'm doing wrong here? I also tried to add the vars twice because its a prepared statement but didn't change anything on the result.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The expression is `ON DUPLICATE KEY`, not `ON DUPLICATED KEY`.  you have an extra `D`.

Comment: Didn't see the forest because of all these trees... thanks mate :D